# Combine to columns with a single formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dynamic-arrays

Using the table below, the formula `=A1:A3` is a dynamic array that reproduces the values of column A.

| column A | column B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 6 |

What I would like to do is use a single formula to reference column A and column B but have both columns return in a single column like below. Is that possible without using VBA?

| column D |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |

Comment: Is column B also a dynamic array that is spilled?

Comment: Columns A and B are both static values. I want to create a dynamic array anywhere that pulls the values from columns A and B. Thanks.

Comment: Are they always 1 to 1 as in the same number of rows in both columns?

Comment: And does order matter?

Comment: It doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this `=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",,TRANSPOSE(A1:B3))&"</s></t>","//s")`.  It should work unless you are on Mac.

If size is an issue as @BigBen points out you can try this.

```
=LET(column1, A1:A3,
     column2, B1:B3,
     size1, ROWS(column1),
     q, SEQUENCE(size1 + ROWS(column2)),
     IF(q>size1, INDEX(column2,q-size1), INDEX(column1,q)))
```

Comment: Note that TEXTJOIN might run into a limit depending on the size of the range and the values in it.

Comment: This is perfect to answer my example. I now realize that there was an oversight with my example where what I want to ask is how to use two dynamic arrays and combine the result into a single column or row, so I'll post another question. Thank you!

Comment: The second formula should work for two dynamic arrays.

Comment: The second formula using `LET` is exactly what I'm looking for and I don't have to post another question for a better example to explain what I'm trying to accomplish. I really have to learn how to use the `LET` function now! Thank you!